# Trigger ('mouseleave') - not working as desired on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, eventtrigger, mouseleave

I have a burger menu button in the header which opens and closes the menu. And I have `hover` and `focus` animations for it.

So when the menu is clicked or tapped or touched (on mobile devices) -  the second time it loses the `hover` and `focus` styles. Everything in the code below is working perfectly, but the trigger `mouseleave` isn't working. I tested my code and found out that on mobile devices when a person clicks on a button, `hover` animation applies there too.  So trigger `mouseleave` should cancel the `hover` effects I have on my burger menu button, but it isn't working.

I have tried everything: I have put this in setTimeout function and tried other different events, too (like testing it out in different browsers). Yet nothing seems to remove that `hover` animation on mobile devices when a user touches or clicks this burger menu button. Please help, as I have been stuck on this for two days.

```
//losing focus for menu toggler on smaller devices
var loseFocusMenu = 0;
$(".c-header-nav__toggle").on("click touch", function(){
    if (loseFocusMenu === 0){
        loseFocusMenu++;
    }else if(loseFocusMenu === 1){
        $(".c-header-nav__toggle").trigger('mouseleave');
        $(".c-header-nav__toggle").trigger('blur');
        loseFocusMenu--;
    }
    
});
```

I am developing a Wordpress theme, so I am using that platform (and obviously that's jquery in the code). Please help

Also that `hover` and `focus` animations are coming from internal styling in the `style` tag and coming from another class that's assigned to the same burger menu button

Comment: I would try to trigger `touchend`...

Comment: no the touchend ain't working either.

Comment: why don't you just add and remove a class on smaller devices. Sounds like media queries would solve your issue.

Comment: And what about a media query that would add the `:hover` rule only on screen sizes bigger than the mobile sizes?

Comment: i have thought about both of these solutions. the thing is my situations is a bit complex i am adding dynamic styles in the internal styling. and if i i want to do this with adding and remove class on smaller devices i would have to add more internal styles and i don't want that as its not good for speed optimisation

Comment: also i need the hover class for smaller devices also. i guess i would have to add more styles for this button only as internal styles

Answer (score 1):

i solved the issue with adding and removing classes. if your hands are tied and u can't do it any other way like in my case than this is the work around